# New Email Dialogue in Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-redemption

Is it possible to create a new email with redemption and open outlook new email dialogue, without outlook running.

I know how to create an email, is it just a case of creating the temporary email save it as an msg, then process start, or can I achieve this via another method.

```
Dim Session As RDOSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession
Dim Msg = Session.GetMessageFromMsgFile(strPath & "" & strFilename, True)
Msg.MessageClass = "IPM.Note"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new items without Outlook running on the system (but it should be installed with a mail profile configured, or at least the MAPI runtime should be installed):

```
' create a new session
Dim Session As RDOSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession
Session.Logon
Set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set Msg = Inbox.Items.Add("IPM.Note")
Msg.BCC = "eugene@astafiev.vvv"
Msg.Subject = "test"
Msg.Display()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, just call `RDOMail.Display(true/false)` (`true` for for modal display). Keep in mind that MAPI forms used to show the message are implemented by outlook.exe, so it will launch anyway if it is not running.